# How to configure ssh to listen to private network IP address?

Tags: ssh, centos7, ip-address

I have a system with centOS 7 installed. And on the second system I have windows 10. Both the machines are connected to private network. Now, I want to access the centOS machine remotely over ssh.

I checked the IP address of my windows machine, and then I edited the

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

file on the centOS system, With the following entries

`ListenAddress <Ip_address_of_window_machine>`

But when I restart the ssh service using the following command

`systemctl restart sshd.service`

I get the following error

`bind to port 22 on <ip-address> failed. cannot assign requested address`

But when I configure entries like this

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress [::]
```

it works fine. But I want to bound my ssh to just particular iP-address

Comment: The CentOS hosts's IP adress should go into `ListenAddress`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then how can I configure ssh on centOS to just listen to some particular IP address?

Comment: By *listen* you mean accept? iptable or firewalld is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

The *ListenAddress* configuration options tells sshd process to bind to a specific network interface on the server. If you want restrict access to a CentOS host then you need to use firewall. Though [firewalld](https://firewalld.org/documentation/howto/open-a-port-or-service.html) is the proper way to go (with zones and so on), old good iptables will do the job:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s a.b.c.d --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j REJECT
```

Where a.b.c.d is the ip address of windows hosts.

**NOTICE: By configuring firewall over the networks you can easily lock yourself out!**